# How to test that my usage of a ConcurrentHashMap is threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have written the code below and want to test its concurrency.
Even though I have used `ConcurrentHashMap`, I am not confident that the code is threadsafe because get and update/replace are used on different lines.
Can anyone suggest how to test this?

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, int> somemap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); 
boolean some_method() {
    somemap.putifAbsent("somekey",value); 
    final int val = somemap.get("somekey");
    if(val < total_count) {
        val++;
    }
    somemap.replace("somekey", val);
}
```

Comment: @Vaibs How does one do that and what would it show? Please elaborate, preferably in an answer.

Comment: use this.. long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();  Or you can use log4j with sleuth trace  ..https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-sleuth-get-trace-id.

Comment: "Thread safe" is a vague description. Better to explain your actual requirement. If your actual requirement is for the value of "somekey" in the map to be incremented by exactly the number of calls to `some_method()`, then No. It's not thread safe.

Comment: It's not safe.  The `putIfAbsent` is OK, but the increment is not.  Use `.compute(...)` to do the whole operation in one step.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone suggest how to test this?

Testing for thread safety is not reliable. The reason is, The specification for a programming language or library may promise that if your multi-threaded program obeys certain rules, then you can expect it to behave in a certain way, but you will practically *never* find a promise that if your program breaks the rules then it will fail to meet your expectations.

I personally have seen a software update go through weeks of unit testing and integration testing, and then be shipped out into the field, where it ran for half a year before a piece of "thread unsafe" code caused it to fail at a customer site.

The only way to be sure that your multi-threaded program will work, is to *prove* that (A) it says what you think it says, and (B) it obeys the rules.

Your example obeys the rules, but I don't think it does what you think it does. It has a race condition. Namely, two threads both could call `get("somekey")` at the same time, and both get the same value. Then they both could compute the same new value, and they both could `put(...)` it back.  Two calls to `some_method()`, but the end result is that the value only goes up by one.

Comment: Hey , Thanks for such a detailed explanation . I was wondering if we can use .compute() so that it follows rule A (it says what you think it says) . Maybe it will be thread safe then

Comment: @Souravgupta, [Javadoc for `compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) says, "The entire method invocation is performed atomically." So, yeah. Seems like it would work for you. Just be aware that if you ever call `compute` with a `remappingFunction` that takes a long time to execute, other threads will be blocked if they try to access the map while the `remappingFunction` is executing. _Your_ remappingFunction would be trivial though: It only returns its given value arg plus 1.